# how to load usercontrols from the assembly using the filename?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, assemblies, loadcontrol

we have a set of usercontrols complied to a dll. we could just load the controls using their classnames by like `ASP.theusercontrol_ascx blah = new ASP.theusercontrol_ascx();`

but if we have dynamic data and load the controls based on the filename (or the control name),
how can we load them like `Page.LoadControl("TheURL/theusercontrol.ascx")`?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't really a *proper* way of doing this.  .ascx files are not meant to be deployable this way.  The code has been compiled to the .dll, but the actual markup from the .ascx file has not.  Even if you follow the official Microsoft documentation on [converting .ascx files to deployable controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx), you lose the ability to call LoadControl based on file name, simply because there is no markup file anymore.

There are a number of [hacks](http://www.timgittos.com/compile-a-user-control-as-a-dll) floating around that let you do it via reflection and embedding the .ascx files as resources.

Aside from that, if you really need to use `LoadControl(filename)`, you will need to copy over the .ascx files.

Comment: If this is the case, we could just instantiate the user control. But the problem is we really need to use strings for the instantiation... And here goes reflection again... =(

Comment: Oh, well, I really have no choice. Reflection saves my life again. Thanks.